Multi-Camera point cloud fusion
I have 4 intel Realsense D455i and an external IMU and jetson Orin, that is mounted on a rectangular robot frame,
the cameras are mounted to cover all 4 sides of the base as shown in the figure below.

I want to fuse the point cloud data from all 4 cameras and use it as a sources for robot localization and mapping using ROS2 navStack2.
Due to the robot's constrains, it cannot rotate at all and I also cannot use Lidar or encoders for the same reason so the only method of obstacle avoidance and localization is the cameras and the IMU .
so my question is how to fuse the point cloud data of the cameras and feed it as one topic to the navStack2?
and will it be effective in mapping/localization?
PS: I have looked at multicamera ROS wrapper launch file but there is nothing on fusing point cloud.
any help or advice will greatly be appreciated.
